# Failed to respond to incoming message using data source row correlation

Tags: parasoft

I am totally new to Parasoft virtualize. I created a virtual asset and added three fields in my data source correlation, My request xml has 4 fields. I am getting this error after processing the request.

```
 <Reason>Failed to respond to incoming message using data source row correlation</Reason>
 <Details>Values in incoming message did not match values in the data source "GetSubscriptionOperationsRequest"</Details>
```

Any suggestions on what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message which you are getting explains your problem.
The virtual asset  cannot correlate your request with data in your data source to build response.

Try to send request with one of the values from column used for Datasource's corelation in your responder. 
That value should be in request's filed used by correlation.

Maybe you should try to add catch all responder to see if you have correct corelation between incoming requests and your responder.
You can also ask Parasoft's technical support for help.